# Inserting data into a second table with some time lag

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server. I am using Management studio 2012 Express edition.

What I want to do is that suppose I have table1 and table2 and suppose someone enters some data into table1, then after some time lag the data must be entered automatically into table2.

I remembered reading about scheduled events, but realized that the express edition does not support Server Agent.

Any suggestions as to how I could tackle this problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this. For example, by creating a stored procedure that inserts the data into table2 then calling this periodically. Could you add some details about your two tables? Also, what does the rest of the system comprise - for example, do you have a web server or front-end as part of the system that could call such a stored procedure?

Comment: You could also use WAITFOR, if you don't need to return success from the first procedure before running the second

Comment: Thank you Mr.@SimonByles and Mr.@MarkSinkinson. As of now there is no front end, I am just trying to learn SQL Server, had been able to implement this using MySQL using scheduled event and temporary table.

@Mark: Sir, even I had thought of using WAITFOR but then it holds up the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints of Express ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)), your best option is to fake an agent job by using Windows Scheduled Tasks and call SQLCMD on a stored procedure every n units of time.  Here is a basic SQLCMD usage rundown: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to go for windows scheduled tasks --> calling sqlcmd, etc

**Another View point :**

I would suggest you to look into Service Broker which is available even in SQL Express edition.

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345113%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5_srvbrk_topic7) :

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Broker is a new platform for building distributed asynchronous database applications. Including an asynchronous, reliable messaging feature in the SQL Server database makes it possible to build a variety of database applications that were difficult, if not impossible, to build before.

You can even invoke [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) using service broker.

This way if you want to scale up your application or implementation then you can as there will be no external dependencies like sqlcmd being called by windows task scheduler, etc.